# Hide table row with value of option box in wordpress with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html

I have a table with an input field in a table row and an option boxe and I want, that the `<tr>` with the input field only appears when a specific value in the option box are selected. So far I have the following coding, it hides my `<tr>` with the input field, but never displays it again.

```
 $script = <<< EOF
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#row_sports').hide(); //works


         if($('#sel_rugby').is(':selected') || $('#sel_climbing').is(':selected')){
             $('#row_sports').show();

         }else{
            $('#row_sports').hide();
         }

    });
</script>
EOF;
        echo $script;


    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '  <tr>';
    echo '      <td>';
    echo '          <select name="sports">';
    echo '              <option>Baseball</option>';
    echo '              <option id="sel_rugby">Rugby</option>';
    echo '              <option>Soccer</option>';
    echo '              <option>Sailing</option>';
    echo '              <option id="sel_climbing">Climbing</option>';
    echo '          </select>';
    echo '      </td>';
    echo '  </tr>';
    echo '  <tr id="row_sports">';
    echo '      <td>';
    echo '          <input name="sports_cl_rg" />';
    echo '      </td>';
    echo '  </tr>';
    echo '</table>';
```

BR & thx,
mybecks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#row_sports').hide(); //works

        $('select').change(function() {
         if($('#sel_rugby').is(':selected') || $('#sel_climbing').is(':selected')){
             $('#row_sports').show();

         }else{
            $('#row_sports').hide();
         }
        });

    });
</script>
```

use change function too.. here it works

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you put id in all options or compare them by the text instead of id it will be event better. I mean use Climbing instead of sel_climbing. Also give id to select to access it as you may have many selects on the page. I changed it to work as you code but you can follow my recommendation if you like. [Demo available here JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3FkV/)

```
 $('select').change(function() {
 alert($('#sports option:selected').text());
    $('#row_sports').hide(); //works
   if($('#sports option:selected').attr('id') == "sel_rugby" || $('#sports option:selected').attr('id') == "sel_climbing"){
     $('#row_sports').show();

 }else{
    $('#row_sports').hide();
 }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#row_sports').hide(); //works

        $('select[name="sports"]').change(function() {
            var trig = ["Rugby", "Climbing"]; // set elements here

            if (trig.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
                $('#row_sports').show();    
            } else {
                $('#row_sports').hide();
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
```